# Trailing math mode with new command

Tags: math-mode, macros

I typed the following code into latex

```
\newcommand{\vm}[1]{v_1,.\; . \;. \;,v_m}
```

hoping to then be able to input `$\vm$` and get the desired output. However, when I do this any text I type after goes into mathmode. I have no idea why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Define it without the `[1]`: `\newcommand{\vm}{v_1,.\; . \;. \;,v_m}` _or_ use `$\vm{}$`. Otherwise your command expects an argument and “eats” the trailing `$` (as if you typed `$\vm{$}`) and you're left with mathmode after the command

Comment: I suppose you are aware of `\ldots` and deliberately replace it by `.\;.\;.\;.`? Surely a matter of taste, but the spacing of `\ldots` looks more appealing than the spread-out version using `\;`.